# What is Serialization/Deserialization and marshalling/unmarshalling with example?

Tags: c#, serialization, marshalling, terminology, unmarshalling

Recently I read about the interface `IClonable` and with it the topics of "serialization" and "marshalling." I would like to know what serialization and marshalling are including some examples of each.

Answer (score 2):

Serialize -A process of converting memory object into binary data/text so that it can be stored on disc.
Deserialize - the reverse of serialization. A process of taking binary data/text from disk and converting it into object in memory. 
[.Net Example](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/article.php/c6595)

wikipedia: [Serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)

Marshaling - a process of passing data between "program" boundaries, like from managed to unmanaged, from one process to another, etc.

wikipedia: [Marshaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29)